# in bash how to convert a git repository that is inside of the git repository into a subtree of that parent git repository?

Tags: git

I'm trying to find a solution to the problem of monorepoisation of the repositories:

```
- chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy (Root Node)
  ├── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-api (Repository)
  ├── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-core (Repository)
  ├── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-engine (Repository)
  ├── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-utils (Repository)
  ├── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-handler (Directory)
  │   ├── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-handler-api (Repository)
  │   └── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-handler-impl (Directory)
  │       └── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-handler-impl-db (Repository)
  └── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-services (Directory)
```

to

```
- chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy (Root Node)
  ├── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-api (Subtree)
  ├── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-core (Subtree)
  ├── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-engine (Subtree)
  ├── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-utils (Subtree)
  ├── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-handler (Directory)
  │   ├── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-handler-api (Subtree)
  │   └── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-handler-impl (Directory)
  │       └── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-handler-impl-db (Subtree)
  └── chatgpt-stackoverflow-proxy-services (Directory)
```

do i have to have a remote repository for subtrees or can i do it "in place"?

im not sure how subtrees work

Comment: What _is_ the problem of "monorepoisation of the repositories"? Do you want to end up with a monorepo? How are these repositories used now? Are you using submodules and want to stop, or what?